# Python ctypes.WinDLL error , _dlopen(self._name, mode) can't be found

Tags: python, windows, dll, dllimport, ctypes

```
ctypes.WinDLL("C:\Program Files\AHSDK\bin\ahscript.dll")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

How can I solve it? I found the _dlopen in `C:\Python26\lib\ctypes\__init__.py`, but I really don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backslashes are an escape character within strings, as demonstrated in the example below:

```
>>> print "C:\Program Files\AHSDK\bin\ahscript.dll"
C:\Program Files\AHSDinhscript.dll
```

You can solve the problem by placing an r before the string, which prevents the backslash from working as an escape character:

```
ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\Program Files\AHSDK\bin\ahscript.dll")
```

Alternately, you could escape the backslashes:

```
ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Program Files\\AHSDK\\bin\\ahscript.dll")
```